# what different between よほど、困ったのだろう " and "さぞ、困ったのだろう"

Tags: word-usage

what different between よほど、困ったのだろう " and "さぞ、困ったのだろう"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are near in nuance like `とても` but the original meanings are different.

### よほど (余程)

Near to `とても` (very, really).

> よほど困ったのだろう
>
> Somebody seems to be really embarrassed.

### さぞ

`さぞ` is an old antique word which appears since Heian-era.

It means like `きっと` and implies that the speaker is guessing something. `さぞ 〜 だろう` is an idiomatic pair.

The original meaning doesn't contain the meaning like `very`, but it implies `very` in most usage.

> さぞ困ったのだろう
>
> Somebody seems to be embarrassed.
>
> さぞお困りのようで。
>
> You seem to be embarrassed.

Comment: 'Embarrassed' isn't really a good match for 困る, is it? I would say it's closer to 'troubled'. 'Embarrassed' is closer to 恥ずかしい.